# How to create url according to the checked checkboxes using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a small form like this

```
<form name="search_something" action=/results method="get">
<input type=checkbox name="choice1">Choice 1<br>
<input type=checkbox name="choice2">Choice 2<br>
<input type=checkbox name="choice3">Choice 3<br>
<input type=checkbox name="choice4">Choice 4<p>
<input type=submit value="Search">
</form>
```

If I check the **choice1** & **choice4** and then I click "Search" it returns me url like this:

```
http://example.com/results?choice2=on&choice4=on
```

But what I want is to make url like this:

```
http://example.com/results?choice=choice2&choice=choice4
```

Please help me.

Comment: Please post you `jquery/javascript` code as well.

Comment: Edit: removed my incorrect comment...

Comment: @Pawan I dont use any jquery code (at this moment), but I clearly understand that I can not do this w/o jquery (I already have jquery library on my page)

Comment: Don't you want the query to be `http://example.com/results?choice=choice2+choice4`?

Comment: And why do you think you need jQuery? You can get this done with plain JavaScript.

Comment: @Michael_Laszlo You wellcome to help solving this problem with Javascript :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like below.(You have to modify your existing html a little bit as below):

**HTML**

```
<form name="search_something" action=/results method="get">
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="choice1">Choice 1<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="choice2">Choice 2<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="choice3">Choice 3<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="choice4">Choice 4<p>
  <input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search">
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#btnSearch").click(function(){
   //var url="http://example.com/results?choice=choice2&choice=choice4"
   var url="http://example.com/results?choice=";
   var flag=false;
   $("input:checkbox[name=choice]:checked").each(function(){
       if(!flag)
       {
         url=url+$(this).val();
         flag=true;// To trace if first query string added
       }
       else
       {
         url=url+"&choice="+$(this).val();
       }         
     });
     //alert(url);
     window.location = url;
   });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9d4fctfn/4/)

Comment: As I understood, the script is looking for the check box with naem "choice" and then ads it to the url with template (choice=+ choice value). Well It's good, but we have some problems... 1. I dont't know jquery at all (so onclick it must go to url, insted of showing alert) 2. In the form there are not only "choice" values but also others... EX: 'http://example.com/results?choice=choice1&choice=choice2&category=category1&subcategory=subcategory1'

Comment: to redirect to a `url` you can use `window.location` instead of `alert` as in updated ans.

Answer (score 1):

By using your html code (not change your html):

```
$(function(){
    var url = "http://example.com/results";
    var choice = "";

    $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
        choice = "";
        $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function (){
            if (this.checked)
                if (choice.length == 0)
                    choice += '?choice=' + this.name;
                else
                    choice += '&choice=' + this.name;
        });
        $('form').attr("action", url + choice);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please tell me how will you get params value from url query string if all params key will same. anyway its very simple, you can use jQuery:

**javascript code:**

```
/**
 * jQuery
 * Document ready function
 */
$(function () {
    // url to post form
    var url = "http://example.com/results?";
    // tmp array var
    var choice = [];
    // when button click
    $("input:button[value='Search']").click(function () {
        // select all checkbox whos name start with choice
        $("input:checkbox[name^='choice']:checked").each(function (i, el) {
            // make url string
            choice += "choice=" + $(el).attr('name') + "&";
        });
        // delete last &
        choice = choice.slice(0, -1);
        // set form action and do post :) Yeah!!
        $('form').attr("action", url + choice).submit();
    });
});
```

**html code:**

```
<form name="search_something" action="" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="choice1">Choice 1 <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="choice2">Choice 2 <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="choice3">Choice 3 <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="choice4">Choice 4 <br />
    <input type="button" value="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: I'll use submitted parameters with djangi views and url resolvers :-). The project ym working on is based on django framework, so when i request url, django understands, that common arguments with different values - is actualy the list of values for some argument. http://open.tm:8080/store/productlist.aspx?section=2&category=7 (there it is, in the left side with yellow button)

Comment: hmmm.. yeah :). got something new today :D Ha!! Haa!! Haaa!!! Thanks I wase'nt aware about Dijango